# How to get return specific String when am using autocompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private AutoCompleteTextView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
       /* String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};*/
        User p = null;

        p = new User("1", "Starhub Pte Ltd","Manager","Jason", "Bourne","");
        userList.add(p);      
        p = new User("2", "Singtel Pte Ltd", "Senior Manager","Ben", "Chia","");
        userList.add(p);  
        p = new User("3", "Ngee Ann Polytechnic", "Senior lecturer","Charles", "Xavier","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("4", "Dreamcity Pte Ltd", "","Ben", "Chia","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("5", "DBS Corporation", "Secretary","Michelle", "Chong","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("6", "OCBC bank", "Deputy finance Manager","YongZheng", "Wong","");
        userList.add(p); 

        AutoCompleteTextView lv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView); // NOTE: change to your autocomplete textview id

        // Adding items to listview

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getUsernames(userList));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);  



    }

    private ArrayList<String> getUsernames(ArrayList<User> users)
    {
        ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(User u : users)

        {
            usernames.add(u.getFirstName() +" "+ u.getLastName() +" "+ u.getCompanyName()); 

        }

        return usernames;
    }
}
```

Let say I want to search "Starhub", I do not want the company name to appear in the search result.

when I type "S", Jason Bourne will appear in my Suggestion, instead of "Jason bourne Starhub"

So far I can done with First and last Name, I don't want the Company Name to be appear, How can I improve it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your own custom `ArrayAdapter<String>` which will provide only the information you want to the AutoCompleteTextView. You can do this as an inner class within your current file or you can write one in it's own external file. Documentation on `ArrayAdapters` will be a good place for you to start finding information about how to extend this class and provide the functionality that you are looking for. Check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use an ArrayAdapter of User instead of an ArrayAdapter of String. And in the class user, override the method toString to return the name of the user.

Here is the source code of an example:

https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/AutoCompleteTextViewHack

Post:

http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2013/12/autocompletetextview-simple-hack-to.html

And this is a simple tutorial:

**Model:**

The model contains 3 fileds: id, name and complete address. The hack overrides the method toString to return the name.

```
/**
 * Hack. Do not modify. To String Must return the name of the cinema, which is the one returned
 * by the AutoCompleteTextView.
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getCinemaName();
}
```

**Main activity**

For the main activity, a simple ArrayAdapter is used:

```
ArrayAdapter<Cinema> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Cinema>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, cinemas);
simpleAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the result:
[image]

**Explication**

Checking the source code of AutoCompleteTextView you can see that it uses the a list adapter to show the list of hints. By using the ArrayAdapter, which in the method getView it uses the method toString to set the text shown:

```
T item = getItem(position);
 if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
     text.setText((CharSequence)item);
 } else {
     text.setText(item.toString());
 }
```

So, by overriding the method toString to output the string to be shown as hint, it could work.

**Extra**
Both AutoCompleteTextView and android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line has problem with old devices. I have tested it on a Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830) with 2.3.5 and both views shows a white background and white text colour, making the text impossible to see.

For the AutoCompleteTextView, the fix is easy:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/simpleAutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
        <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

And for the dropdown item, the source code could be found in the internet, which the app could have a local version with modification of colours:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
/>
```